# AutoML training pipeline job failed. Where can I find the logs?

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I am using Vertex AI's AutoML to train a model an it fails with the error message show below.  Where can I find the logs for this job?

> Training pipeline failed with error message: Job failed. See logs for details.

[image: Training pipeline failed]

Comment: Can you please check the logs by running this query: resource.labels.service="aiplatform.googleapis.com" 
inside Operations > Logging > Logs Explorer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue just now, raised a case with Google who told me how to find the error logs.

In GCP Log Explorer, you need a filter of `resource.type = "ml_job"` (make sure your time range is set correctly, too!)